# Using QtScript outside my main form

Tags: c++, qt

I am using **Qt5**, and trying to learn on how to make an application scriptable.

For this I created a main window that contains some *text edits*, *labels*, etc. I then added an option called "*script console*" to that forms' menu in order for me to open a second form containing just a *text edit* and a *button* called "*Evaluate*".

What I was aiming at was being able to use that second form and through *Qt script engine* be able to set or get values from my main form, and generally be able to script various functions.

What I tried doing was set up the engine like this

```
scriptingconsole::scriptingconsole(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::scriptingconsole)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QScriptValue appContext = myScriptEngine.newQObject(parent);
    myScriptEngine.globalObject().setProperty("app", appContext);
}
```

I don't get what I was expecting though.

If I try to evaluate the expression "**app**" I get **null** as an output.

This works fine if I use *myScriptEngine.newQObject(parent)* with an object inside the current class (if instead of **parent** I enter **this**), but I want to be able to access object in other classes too (hopefully all public slots that are used by my app in general).

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here and how can I use my scripting console
class to access public slots from my main window?

Comment: 1. Is your `scriptingconsole` a [**modal dialog**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs)? 2. Where did you instantiate `myScriptEngine`?

Comment: The GUI that I use as a simple terminal named script console has also its' implementation in the cpp file and a header where I instantiate the engine as such _QScriptEngine myScriptEngine;_.

Comment: You didn't answer my first question. Could you describe how did you instantiate your custom dialog, and how did you call the dialog?

Comment: Yes, this dialog is instantiated from the mainWindows private section as this *scriptingconsole qScripConsole;*. And so each time a user presses the *open console* button I just execute *qScripConsole.show();*

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. So what you want is to call `app` from the script to manipulate the public slot of main window, am I right at this part?

Comment: Yes thats the general idea, because I want to make my application scriptable, which that means that I somehow must be able to access all public slots from all the various classes that I have declared, and not just slots from the class that my scriptEngine is instantiated in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68714/discussion-between-tay2510-and-dearn44).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's wrong?

I guess it's because you didn't explicitly pass the pointer, which points to your main form, to the constructor of your `scriptingconsole`. That's why you got `NULL` as a result. (`NULL` is default, as you can see `QWidget *parent = 0` in every `QWidget` constructor)

This happens if your object is not dynamically instantiated.

## Solution

Dynamically allocate `scriptingconsole` in your main form:

```
scriptingconsole* myScriptConsole;

//...

myScriptConsole = new scriptingconsole(this); 
//                                     ^^^^
//                              pass the pointer which points to parent widget
```

Answer (score 1):

The Qt documentation of QScriptEngine::newQObject says:

*Creates a QtScript object that wraps the given QObject object, using the given ownership. The given options control various aspects of the interaction with the resulting script object.*

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#newQObject

i.e. it *wraps* a QObject..  You are probably passing NULL to newQObject, for whatever reason.  Try setting a breakpoint and evaluating the value of 'parent'.

Comment: Yes that is true, my error as Tay pointed out was in the way I instantiated the script console inside my mainWindow